use textures with displacement map on large scale terrains
I have created a landscape with a HightMap (exr from Gaea). To use the Hightmap, I took a plane (200x200m, 100 subdivision) and applied a subdivision surface modifier 5/5 and a displacement modifier, with the hight map as image. I have applied the modifiers.
Now I want to use a ground texture that has a displacement map. The problem is that the HightMap is already very large and high-resolution, as described above. If I want to use my texture with displacement, I would have to apply another adaptive subdivision surface modifier, which cannot be the solution because its beyond the capacity of any graphics card. The question is how I can use a texture with displacement on such a large heightmap.
My approach was, to divide the mesh of the landscape and use the texture with the displacement only the part in the foreground. But I don't think that this is an elegant solution. You can see the transition between the two textures and it would be nice to have a non destructive workflow.


Have you tried adaptive subdivision? (If needed with an additional well-placed adaptive camera.)

The problem is I need two displacement modifiers: one for the hight map which already needs to be at "render: 5" and a second (adaptive) one for the texture, which is overkill.

You should be able to get by with a single adaptive subdivision, but you need to tweak the settings
